# wrong entry in switch statement how to loop back to the first case? c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

So here is my code

```
  int intNumber1, intNumber2, intResult, operation;
  cout << "enter two integer values: ";
  cin >> intNumber1 >> intNumber2;

  cout << "enter (1) for addition, or (2) for subtraction" << endl;
  cin >> operation;

  switch (operation)
  {

        case '1':
              intResult = intNumber1 + intNumber2;
             cout << intResult << endl ;
              break;

        case '2':

              intResult = intNumber1 - intNumber2;
              cout << intResult << endl; 
              break;

        default:
              cout << "wrong entry please enter a valid choice - 1 for addition, or 2 for subtraction. " << endl;
              cin >> operation;
              break;


  }


  return 0;
```

so I'm only allowed to use if/switch statement and not use any kind of loops. Is there is any way to make the program start again and let the user choose an operation?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use a loop? That is exactly what a programmer would use in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what I've done is simple. I created a function that holds your switch cases. Basically, what doing this does, is that when your main function runs, it will run the userChoice function which displays the prompts and allows the user to input an option. If the user enters anything other then 1 or 2, the switch will go to default, display an error message, and run the function userChoice again. This does not loop back to the first case and asks the user for what operator they want, but calls the function userChoice again, which in turn is like restarting the program or looping it without a loop and prompting for user input again.

## include

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void userChoice(); //Function prototype

int main() {

userChoice(); //Function for menu prompts and user entry
return 0;
}

//Function I created that holds your whole program

void userChoice() {
int intNumber1, intNumber2, intResult, operation;
cout << "enter two integer values: ";
cin >> intNumber1 >> intNumber2;

cout << "enter (1) for addition, or (2) for subtraction" << endl;
cin >> operation;
switch (operation)
{
case 1:
    intResult = intNumber1 + intNumber2;
    cout << intResult << endl;
    break;

case 2:

    intResult = intNumber1 - intNumber2;
    cout << intResult << endl;
    break;

default:
    cout << "wrong entry. " << 
    endl << "Restarting program.";
    userChoice(); //Calls/restarts the function
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a `do{}while()` to check a condition - if you are not allowed to use this you can use a `label` and use `goto` in your default but use this wisely. Another creative idea is to make the switch inside a function. Call the function and the switch will fire - then if wrong input call the function again - a void function should be fine for what you are trying to do in the code you gave above.
I hope this answer helps!